# Can Gem5 simulator be used to differentiate between different type of DRAM traffic?

Tags: simulator, gem5

I want to differentiate between whether the traffic coming to DRAM is coming from page table walker (that is due to address translation, after it misses in the TLB), or it is other traffic (not coming from page table walker). Can I use Gem5 to do that?

Comment: It would be good to clarify if you want that on logs or C++ code. But I don't know the answer. If in C++ code, also learn to debug gem5 with Eclipse, it will help tremendously. Also ask on mailing list.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stacked. Just check [Gem5](http://gem5.org/Main_Page) and it is possible, but what did you try?

Answer (score 0):

A memory controller in gem5 can differentiate among different masters via the Request::masterId. A master will ask for a unique masterId at construction time, by using the System::getMasterId method.
Every time it will allocate a new packet/request, it will tag it with its own masterId.

So if you want to add a hook in the dram memory controller to perform some action if the request is coming from a specific master, you can easilly do that.
If you are just interested on high level stats, like the bandwidth utilization of a master, the DRAM controller should print that in the stat file (It would print average bw/latency per master).

Having said that I don't know which architecture/table-walker you are using.
The ARM table walker has its own masterId (even though its initialization is a little bit convoluted, I should fix this), but maybe that's not the case for the architecture you are using.
Anyway it should be trivial to modify the HTW to ask the System for a unique masterId token.